# Adding text to simulink 3d plot, independent of coordinates

Tags: matlab, text, plot, coordinates, simulink

I am doing a small simulation on matlab simulink, and I need to write a text on the graph, independent of coordinates. To explain more, in my simulation, the cameraposition in the axes properties always changes(3d plot), so the coordinates that are displayed on the graph change too.
What I want is to add text to the graph (let's say bottom left), without having to specify coordinates for the text box.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the options in the '[text](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/text_props.html)' function?

You could do something like:

```
xmin = min(get(gca,'xlim'));
ymin = min(get(gca,'ylim'));
zmin = min(get(gca,'ylim'));
text(xmin,ymin,zmin,'text')
```

You might also need to play around with the align options in 'text'

Comment: The thing is if I do so, the text will over plot what I'm drawing on the graph. I only have some space at the corners where I can fit a text box.

Comment: Ah, okay, so you are trying to put the text box outside of the plot itself then, but inside the figure window?

If so then maybe something like: 
xpos = min(xmin+xmin/10, xmin-xmin/10); 
ypos = min(ymin+ymin/10, ymin-ymin/10); 
text (xpos,ypos, 'test', 'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','cap' )

This should put the text in a consistent position relative to the bottom left corner

Comment: But the fact that the camera position is changing inside the simulation makes this method useless. Just imagine that my plot is a 3d object, that I need -at one moment- to rotate the "camera" around it, while displaying a text saying that "time has freezed". Desplaying text at xmin and ymin would make it disappear when the camera is rotating.

Comment: Sorry, possibly I am misunderstanding your question then. Would you mind expounding a bit? First, what command are you using to plot? Are you using plot, drawnow...? Second, where is the plotting being done? Is it being done in a Simulink block such as "Matlab Function" or "Interpreted Matlab Function?" And third, when you say "Displaying text at xmin and ymin would make 'it' disappear," what is 'it'? The camera, the 3d object, or the textbox itself? Thanks

Comment: I am using the plot3 function to plot my graph, and text drawnow to display textbox. The plotting is being done in a "normal" Simulink block. And third, I was wrong by saying it "disappears". What I meant with "it" is the textbox by itself, and "disappearing" is due to the fact that the camera is rotating around a fixed point. So the textbox would literally be hidden at one point of this rotation. I hope I'm being clear enough, I lack technical words in matlab language. Thanks

Comment: Great! Thanks for the clarification! Hmm... so if I am understanding correctly, you would like the "time has freezed" textbox to stay in the same place relative to the plotting window (and not the constantly changing plotting axis) over the course of the simulation. I tried the above commands and they seemed to work for me so I think that possibly the problem is where the commands are being placed. Would you be able to provide some code or pseudo-code of how you are plotting when the textbox keeps disappearing so that I can try to replicate the problem?

Comment: `set(fig_axes, 'CameraPosition', [a+b*cos(o),a+b(1+cos(o)),a+b*sin(-o)]);
o=o-2*pi/1500`
Basically this is the rotation of the camera inside the code. I added the text box here. So at every iteration, the value of o will change, changing the position of the camera. Note that I already set my x,y, and z limits.

Comment: Assuming that you are doing the 'text' command after 'set' and before you change the value of o I am stumped and not sure why it won't work for you. I'm sorry that I couldn't be more useful :(